# Is it a bad clutch or something else? Help!

Tags: clutch, infiniti, g35, slipping

I have 2006 infiniti g35 coupe sports package, I recently bought the car and all of a sudden the clutch starts reving very high. I'm talking in the morning it was fine but in the afternoon of the same day she started to rev high. But once I rev her up to 5-6000 RPM she catches fine and takes off any ideas if this is the clutch? itself or something like the master cylinder or slave cylinder?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

From my experience with manual transmissions, the symptom you describe points to a worn out clutch.  Only one time did I find that the slave cylinder would not retract all the way causing the clutch to slip.  Though driving that way, even a short while, significantly shortened the clutches lifespan.

Comment: So probably best to get a new clutch kit installed?